# Django Inline Formset to edit one value via ManyToMany

Tags: django, forms

I'm trying to make a form to edit the value of a ManyToMany field from its parent model. As an example, I have something similar to these three models:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField()


class Word(models.Model):
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    word = models.CharField()
    entries = models.ManyToManyField(Entries, null=True, blank=True)


class Entries(models.Model):
    entry = models.CharField()
```

Each Language will have about 50 words. Each Word will have one or two entries each.

I'm generating the formset to edit the entries for a given language like this:

```
class WordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Word
        hidden = ('language', )

PronounFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Language, Word,
         can_delete=False, extra=0, form=WordForm)
```

This gives me a `<select>` which allows me to add/remove an Entry into Word.entries. However, I want to allow the user to edit the field Entries.entry *directly* (i.e. the field `Entries.entry` should be in a CharField(). How do I modify my WordForm to allow this?

I know there are probably better ways to do this (e.g. a different database schema), but I'm heavily constrained by a legacy implementation.

Comment: what do you mean, exactly, by _directly_?

Comment: I'd like the form to show the `entry` field of the Entries model in a CharField()

Comment: Do you want to be able to edit existing entries or just allow the user to add new ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the entry to be a text field, you can add a custom field to your `ModelForm`, and make sure the default field is not shown by explicitly identifying which fields should be shown:

```
class WordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Word
        hidden = ('language', )
        fields = ('word',)
    entries = forms.CharField()
```

Your form validation logic should be like this:

```
for form in formset:
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.language = # select the language here
    obj.save()

    entry = Entries.objects.get_or_create(entry=form.cleaned_fields['entries'])
    obj.entries.add(entry)
    obj.save()
```

Keep in mind with this implementation, you can't edit fields using this form (since the character field will always be empty when the form is rendered).